# Can Somebody use Takekoputa to fly?

Tags: helicopter

[Takekoputa(タケコプター)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?es_sm=93&biw=1366&bih=599&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%E7%AB%B9%E3%81%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%BC&oq=%E7%AB%B9%E3%81%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%BC&gs_l=img.3..0l9j0i4i37.212324.212324.0.212643.1.1.0.0.0.0.175.175.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.174.75kOga4_3xM#tbm=isch&q=%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B1%E3%82%B3%E3%83%97%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC) is one of the most famous and common gadget in the Japanese manga series **Doraemon**.

Regardless the power issue, Can it be used to fly in real world, as like as in the animation?

[image]

Comment: Wow!!! I love Doraemon!!

Comment: in some countries, its also known as the 'bamboo copter' .. Anyways, I love that!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a manner of speaking yes (although its highly unlikely). If the propellor on his head can generate enough lift to get his mass off the ground there is nothing to say he cant fly. That does not mean that the flight will be very stable or controllable but it may lift off. Since the animal does not have the equivalent of a [tail rotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_rotor) the torque effect generated from the propellor may spin him around. It does appear there may be flyable toy versions

[image]

Although for what its worth there is no identifiable power plant that is spinning this head propellor...

Comment: Doraemon is actually a robot, so presumably the power plant is internal.  Of course, this particular show is aimed at children, so relevant details are usually light...

Comment: I know almost nothing of aviation besides being a minor fan of planes and airshows, but this question tickled me enough to sign up, just to say: Could Doraemon be using a tip jet rotor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_jet) to get around the torque issue?

Comment: Yes, Doraemon is a robot. But Nobita, Shizuka and Giant are presumably children. A great show anyway :)

Comment: @vasin you forgot Sunio.. That's not fair..!!

Answer (score 6):

I assume that the thing on his head is a propellor

If so, then in theory yes, it could fly. If the propellor rotates fast enough, and the rest of him is light enough.

Note that his body, however, would rotate in the opposite direction to the propellor, likely making him uncontrollable.

In theory he could lift off the ground, in practice he would almost certainly be uncontrollable

Comment: Could Doraemon be using a tip jet rotor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_jet) to get around the torque issue?

Comment: Yes, or two contra-rotating rotors, perhaps - although they would appear to be very close together, I see no reason why it's any less plausible than the rest :) to rotate fast enough they would have t be supremely well engineered anyway. Perhaps the rotor even alternates direction

Comment: Or he could use a reaction wheel in his body to counter torque :)

Comment: If we're assuming that thing on its head is a propeller I have to assume the big red ball on its tail is the required anti-collision light :)